# Surface refresh rate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

How does one determine the refresh rate of a fluid in the following example: 
A laminar flow of a certain (lets say 10 ml/hour) volume/time of a certain fluid goes along a certain surface area (lets say 1 cm^2). How does one determine the amount of fluid that is refreshed on that surface in what time?

Also, is it a lot different if you have a volume (lets say 1 cm^3) instead of a surface?

Comment: Laminar or turbulent flow?

Comment: It's a laminar flow, I added it in the question, thank you.

Comment: What does the flow look like? is the surface exposed? Also, is there a rigorous definition of "amount of fluid refreshed"?

Comment: It's a medium for cells in a closed system (a chip, more specific "organ on a chip") where the flow goes thru a microfluïdic channel. The surface is exposed to the medium (I don't know the exact dimensions of the surface). With the amount of fluid refreshed, I mean when you "push" the medium with a flow rate of lets say, 10 ml/hour, can you calculate how many times the surface refreshes with new medium in a day for example.

Comment: @Guido If the fluid is mixed with other molecules, then we can estimate the rate of mass transfer. If the fluid has a different temperature than the surface, then the rate of heat transfer can be estimated.